# How to pipe parameters to PowerShell Advanced Function?

Tags: function, powershell

I'm using parameter validation in an Advanced Function (PowerShell v4):

```
Function Test-It {
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='set1')]
Param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set1',Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [ValidatePattern("regex1")][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='set1',Position=1,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [ValidatePattern("regex2")][string]$param2
)
```

I want to pipe param1 and param2 to the Test-It function from a hashtable:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % { $_.Name, $_.Value } | TestIt
```

The problem is each name-value pair is being passed as one parameter rather than two parameters in position 1, position 2.  I've tried using $args[n] but the parameter syntax won't allow it.

How can I pipe a key-value pair as two distinct parameters to an Advanced Function?

Comment: to evade the question, you can use ordered, not hash

Comment: If I refactor my hashtable to look like this: `'param1'='value1';'param2'='value2'` and I pipe like this: `$ht.GetEnumerator() | % { $_ } | Test-It` perhaps named parameters will work. I removed `Position=n` from the parameter definition... still testing...

Comment: pkew I'm retarded, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+splatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess answer depends on your end goal. It seems like all you want to achieve is to use combination of key/value from hash table as a value for two parameters. If that is the case, than I would recommend using different pipeline binding: `ByPropertyName`. This one takes piped object and looks for properties that match parameter name (it can also be parameter alias). If name of the parameters is not important you can make it as simple as:

```
function Test-Hash {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String]$Key,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String]$Value
    )
    process {
        "Key = $Key, Value = $Value"
    }
}

@{
    a = 1
    b = 2
}.GetEnumerator() | Test-Hash
```

If names of the parameters should be different, you can either define an alias, or use awesome feature of `ByPropertyName` binding: the fact that you can pass script block to such parameter with similar behaviour to the one used in `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
function Test-AwesomeHash {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String]$First,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String]$Second
    )
    process {
        "First = $First, Second = $Second"
    }
}

@{
    a = 1
    b = 2
}.GetEnumerator() | Test-AwesomeHash -First { $_.Key } -Second { $_.Value }
```

Any validators that you set up there should work as expected.

Comment: This works: `$ht.GetEnumerator() | AdvFunction -NamedParam1 { $_.Key } -NamedParam2 { $_.Value }` thx!

Comment: @JaquelineVanek because that would do something completely different. Splatting is useful when hash table keys match parameters (so keys are used only to match parameter and argument), and would require multiple hash tables to get multiple results. Here both keys and values are used as arguments of the function and one hashtable can produce as many results as you need.